# Finding angles of a quadrilateral

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, quadrilateral, angle

There is a quadrilateral. Length of all $4$ sides are known (lets say $a,b,c,d$).

All $4$ angles are $\leq 180^{\circ}$, but their exact value is unknown.
lets say the four angle names are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\omega$ (in this order)

refer this fig: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejefG.jpg (img courtesy: @sinbadh)

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ has following relation (1st):

$\alpha = \beta/2 + 90^{\circ}$

Is this info enough to find a unique solution for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\omega$

If yes, could you help provide their solution.

If no, lets make a relation (2nd) between $\alpha$ and $\gamma$:

$\gamma = 180^{\circ} - \alpha$

Now is it possible to find a unique solution for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\omega$

In short i need $\alpha = f(a,b,c,d)$

----- UPDATE -----

With  the help of @sinbadh's answer posted below, on using law of cosine I was able to find $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ as $f(a,b,c,d)$ only if the second relation ($\gamma = 180 - \alpha$) is true.

However, it would help me more if I can find the angles with only 1st relation (not 2nd relation)

Comment: You haven't quite specified everything uniquely.  Which pair of sides is the angle $\alpha$ measured between?

Comment: i apologize for the poor description. but $(a,b,c,d) are just random names of sides. e.g. in the answer posted by sinbad below, the 1st quadrilateral is the one i am interested in.

Comment: and my bad, the second relation is between $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ not $\alpha$ and $\omega$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In figure, by Cosine's Law we know $AB$. Then, by the same law, we know $\angle ADB$.Finally, as it is a convex quadrilateral (cuase all angles are not mayor than 180), sum of all angles are 360. Those, we get $\angle DBC$

[image]

If quadrilateral isn't convex, only can happen two situations:[image]

[image]

Both of them are equivalent to the first case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment sinbadh. yes, the quadrilateral is indeed convex as evident from each angles <=180. I need to figure out values of angles e.g. $\alpha = f(a,b,c,d)$

Answer (score 1):

The possible values of $\cos \alpha$ are given by the real roots on the interval $[-1,1]$ of the cubic polynomial
$$
P(x) \equiv 8 b d x^3 - 4 ab x^2 + (2 ad - 6bd)x - (a^2 + b^2 - 2 ab - c^2 + d^2) = 0,
$$
if any such roots exist.

To show this, set up a Cartesian coordinate system such that the angle $\alpha$ is at the origin and the side $a$ lies along the $x$-axis.  We can derive the coordinates of the vertex opposite $\alpha$ in two ways.  By considering displacements along sides $a$ and $b$, the coordinates of the opposite point are
$$
(a - b \cos \beta, b \sin \beta) = (a + b \cos (2 \alpha), - b \sin (2 \alpha)),
$$
where we have used the relationship $\beta = 2 \alpha - \pi$ in the second step.
On the other hand, if we consider the displacements along sides $c$ and $d$, the coordinates of this same point must be
$$
\left(d \cos \alpha + c \cos(\omega + \alpha - \pi), d \sin \alpha + c \sin(\omega + \alpha - \pi)\right) = \left(d \cos \alpha - c \cos(\psi), d \sin \alpha - c \sin(\psi)\right),
$$
where $\psi \equiv \alpha + \omega$.  These two coordinates must be equal to each other, meaning that we have two equations and two unknowns ($\alpha$ and $\psi$):
\begin{align*}
a + b \cos (2 \alpha) &= d \cos \alpha - c \cos \psi \\
- b \sin (2 \alpha) &= d \sin \alpha - c \sin \psi
\end{align*}
Isolating $\psi$ on one side of each equation, squaring each equation, and adding them together then yields
$$
(a + b \cos (2 \alpha) - d \cos \alpha)^2 + (b \sin (2 \alpha) + d \sin \alpha)^2 = c^2,
$$
which, when expanded out, yields
$$
a^2 + b^2 + d^2 + 2ab \cos (2\alpha) - 2ad \cos \alpha + 2bd [-\cos (2 \alpha) \cos \alpha + \sin (2 \alpha) \sin \alpha] = c^2.
$$

Now let $x = \cos \alpha$.  This means, in particular, that $\cos (2\alpha) = 2x^2 - 1$ and 
\begin{align*}
-\cos (2 \alpha) \cos \alpha + \sin (2 \alpha) \sin \alpha &= -(2 \cos^2 \alpha - 1) \cos \alpha + 2 \sin^2 \alpha \cos \alpha \\ &= -(2x^2 - 1)x + 2(1 - x^2)x \\ &= - 4x^3 + 3x.
\end{align*}
Thus, plugging this in, we get that $x = \cos \alpha$ must satisfy the polynomial
$$
a^2 + b^2 + d^2 + 2ab (2x^2 - 1) - 2ad x + 2bd (- 4x^3 + 3x) = c^2,
$$
from which the condition $P(x) = 0$ (with $P(x)$ defined as above) follows.

This is about as far as it's worth going analytically, to be honest.  Closed-form solutions to cubic polynomials exist, but they're notoriously hard to work with analytically.  However, it's not too hard to derive a necessary condition that there be at least one root in the interval $[-1,1]$.  We have
$$
P(-1) = c^2 - (a + b + d)^2
$$
and
$$
P(1) = c^2 - (a + b - d)^2
$$
But for the quadrilateral to exist in the first place, we must have $ c < a + b + d$;  thus, $P(-1) < 0$.  If $P(1) \geq 0$, there will necessarily be at least one root of $P$ in the interval $[-1,1]$;  this occurs when
$$
c \leq | a + b - d|.
$$
However, this is only a sufficient condition for a solution to exist;  I haven't been able to prove that it is a necessary condition as well.

Comment: I am very much thankful to u for all the effort you made for the explanation. I understood your point very well. I used, wolframalpha to [solve for x](http://goo.gl/eNNrDn), and confirmed there is not a unique solution for it. Well, this implies I can't use only relation 1 to find concrete answers for my work & I have to use relation 2 as well. Since Sinbadh's hint helped me to get the ans, I am marking it as "correct answer". Although I want to mark ur answer as "correct answer" as well, but I can't. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer either. I apologize sincerely.